# If we use the middle index as pivot, what would be the wrost case of quick sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

So the worst case of quick sort is when we choose a pivot that always produces either 0 elements higher than it or 0 lower than. This happens when we use the first or last index as a pivot in a sorted array. But using the middle index, a sorted array would be divided in half in each recursive call so that it would be `O(n*log(n))`. But then, what is the worst case of the quick sort when we use the middle index? What situations would produce an `O(n²)`runtime?

## Edit

I'm putting a implementation of quick sort:

```
partitionate(array, start, end, pivotIndex){
    pivot = array[pivotIndex];
    counter = 0;
    swap array[pivotIndex] with array[end-1];

    for index = 0; index < end; index++:
        if(array[index] <= pivot){
            swap array[index] with array[counter];
            counter++;
        } 
  
    newPivotIndex = counter -1;

    return newPivotIndex;
}


quickSort(array, start, end) =
 {
    if(start == end) return;
    pivotIndex = floor((end-start)/2);
  
    newPivotIndex = partitionate(array, start, end, pivotIndex);
  
    quickSort(array, start, newPivotIndex);
    quickSort(array, newPivotIndex+1, end);
    
 }
```

Comment: ANY fixed choice of the pivot index runs the risk that the value at that index happens to be the lowest or highest value in the range being sorted.  You seem to understand why choosing the first or last index is a bad idea - this can easily happen if the array is already (mostly) sorted.  If you choose the middle index each time, having this always be the worst choice doesn't correspond to any likely order of the array - you're either very unlucky, or someone is maliciously ordering the array to trigger your worst-case behavior..

Comment: There are several different implementations of QuickSort, so this question cannot be answered without including the code for the actual version of QuickSort that you use.

Comment: When you say “the middle index,” do you mean “the index halfway down the array,” or do you mean “the median element?”

Comment: @trincot I wrote an Edit with the implementation of quickSort.

Comment: @templatetypedef I mean just the index halfway down the array.

Comment: Vitor, the part that you described as *"Change the array so that all items..."* should be written out in pseudo code, as that part has also several possible implementations, leading to different arrays, even though they all meet the said requirement.

Comment: @trincot Changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What situations would produce an O(n²)runtime?

For Lomuto partition scheme, when all elements are equal.

For any partition scheme, where the middle element is always the smallest or largest value in that partition. The data pattern to cause this to happen depends on the actual implementation.